# Converting text to html

Tags: html, text

In a database, I have the text `<b>ISBOLD</b><i>isitalic</i>`

How do I do that if I pull out this string, I will see

**ISBOLD** *isitalic*

and not

`<b>ISBOLD</b><i>isitalic</i>`

Comment: when you say 'pull out' where are you display this string data? in any case you need to do Character Escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo it! (if it's in PHP anyway)

Answer (score 0):

just echo the text, it should handle itself if it is php on your server-side..

Else, use javascript, `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML("Your html code here");`

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of ways:

1. You basically have to convert the special characters into the entity references.
   That means changing `<` to `&lt;` and  `>` to `&gt;` etc.. In PHP there is a function which does this for you called [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities)
2. Wrap that output in an `<xmp>` tag.

Option one is probably the better method.

Comment: Isn't converting < to &lt; going the opposite direction being asked for?

Comment: I think it's a bit of "lost in translation" in the question. The way I read it, he's echoing out a string, and the browser is displaying it as HTML, whereas he wants to see the string in plain text. Converting a HTML string to HTML shouldn't be a problem..?